# ASP.NET ComboBox fill and bind question

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, c#-3.0

I have long time to catch up with ASP.NET, now i need to create an app that has
a FormView and several comboboxes in Edit and Insert templates.

I use ASPxComboBox but this wont make any difference.

I kina try to understand if i can have a SqlDataSource to fill the list of the combobox and bind the value into another SqlDataSource. This seems to be a goal that can never achieved. In windows this would be an easy normal task.

Now what i want to ask is the most efficient way to do this.

Any help appreciated.

[EDIT]

I need to achieve fill a ComboBox from the database (DataSource) and bind it to another (DataSource) something similar in windows forms.

Comment: Why do you want to bind it to another datasource than you want to fill it from? If you only want to set the SelectedItem according to another table's foreignkey, than you could do that without binding it to that table.

Comment: Do you have an example of a sample showing how to fill a combobox from a database table and still this will show the value from the datasource it is binded...eg. you have a customer and you want to show with a combobox in what category he is...you have the categories in a table...you use the FormView and templates...you use a combobox for this field, you need to show all the categories and this to change according to which record you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wants a refresh on ASP.NET FormView and DropDownlist...

[FormView Step by Step](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/FormView-Control.aspx)

[DropDownList in a FormView](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=1423)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SqldatSource-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx). You will find some examples on how to bind a SqlDataSource to ASP.Net Controls like DropDownList.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
          id="SqlDataSource1"
          runat="server"
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
          SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, Address FROM Employees"
          UpdateCommand="UPDATE Employees SET Address=@Address WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID">
          <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="Address" ControlId="TextBox1" PropertyName="Text"/>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="EmployeeID" ControlId="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
          </UpdateParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>

      <asp:DropDownList
          id="DropDownList1"
          runat="server"
          DataTextField="LastName"
          DataValueField="EmployeeID"
          DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Ok, thats the easy task, how do you now bind the Value field in another datasource...say you have a datasource with some properties and need to show the correct value of this datasource to the combobox where fills from another datasource. I guess i wasn clear enough.

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to achieve. Edit your original questions with these additonal informations.